# Expected Declaration in UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mapkit

If I want to perform logic in a ViewController I put it in a function eg viewDidLoad or a button action.

But if I want to perform logic when a UITableViewCell class has been loaded, how do I do this?

```
class MapKitViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var the_map: MKMapView!  
}
```

I want to set `the_map`'s delegate as itself, and add a polyline. I was able to do this in another viewController in viewDidLoad. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in `cellForRow` method. In this method, you are first dequeing a cell, set correct state and then return the cell to display on the window. You can do whatever you want to this cell element before returning it in this `cellForRow` method

Comment: perfect. Wasn't thinking about it the right way. Thanks heaps.